# Dropzone Laravel 10

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to upload photos via Dropzone but when I try they don't send. The function dd($request->file('file)) is not executed because file('file') is null, and I don't know why. Here is my script:

```
<script>
    Dropzone.options.fileUpload = {
        url: '{{route('admin.product.form')}}',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpg, .jpeg, .png",
        dictRemoveFile: "Remove",
        accept: function(file) {
            let fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onloadend = function() {

                let content = fileReader.result;
                $('#file').val(content);
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
            }
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-complete");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Route:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware('admin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/product', [ProductController::class, 'index'])->name('product');
    Route::post('/product', [ProductController::class, 'doProduct'])->name('product.form');
});
```

Controller:

```
  public function doProduct(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            dd($file);
            $filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->storeAs('uploads', $filename); // Записване на файла в директория 'uploads'
        }


        echo 'hello';
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Variants</h5>
                <div class="mb-8">
                    <div class="dropzone dropzone-file-area" id="fileUpload">
                        <div class="dz-default dz-message">
                            <h3 class="sbold">Drop files here to upload</h3>
                            <span>You can also click to open file browser</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```